# php function to echo javascript string

Tags: php, javascript

Is the a proper php function to echo javascript string?
I want to the php function to echo something like this:

```
<!--/* OpenX Interstitial or Floating DHTML Tag v2.8.7 */-->
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
//<![CDATA[
var ox_u = 'extremely_long_url_string';
if (document.context) ox_u += '&context=' + escape(document.context);
document.write("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='" + ox_u + "'></scr"+"ipt>");
//
// ]]></script>
```

I know I can put it all in one line and use \ to escape all the quotes BUT I'm looking for a more elegant & effective solution.

Comment: `"<scr"+"ipt` Why are you concatenating strings, where it isn't necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use HEREDOC:

```
$a=<<<BLA
<!--/* OpenX Interstitial or Floating DHTML Tag v2.8.7 */-->
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
//<![CDATA[
var ox_u = 'extremely_long_url_string';
if (document.context) ox_u += '&context=' + escape(document.context);
document.write("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='" + ox_u + "'></scr"+"ipt>");
//
// ]]></script>
BLA;
```

and then you can simply

```
echo $a;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [heredoc-syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

> Heredoc text behaves just like a double-quoted string, without the double quotes. This means that quotes in a heredoc do not need to be escaped […].

Comment: Or just put your JS between `?>` and `<?php`.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing specific or only for JavaScript but every output feature works for JavaScript. You can just print the out of `<?php ?>` tag like

```
<?php 
session_start(); //just an example PHP code
?>
<!--/* OpenX Interstitial or Floating DHTML Tag v2.8.7 */-->
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
//<![CDATA[
var ox_u = 'extremely_long_url_string';
if (document.context) ox_u += '&context=' + escape(document.context);
document.write("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='" + ox_u + "'></scr"+"ipt>");
//
// ]]></script>
```